# Salesforce Inbox + Einstein Activity Capture - create new contact prompt disappeared

Tags: gmail, inbox, einstein-activity-capture

My client has been using Salesforce Inbox for a while, and now asked my to turn on EAC. Now that EAC is on, he is no longer prompted to Log the Email after sending it. Which is fine when a contact exists in SF, because it will auto-sync. However, when there is no matching contact, he would still like to be prompted so that he can easily create the new contact. He doesn't want to take the extra step of loading the side navigation and creating a contact, he wants to be prompted.
Can anyone advise me as to how to turn on the prompt?

Comment: Not sure. Would the Contact sync from EAC potentially auto-create those contacts?

Comment: I guess you need to save the contact in the folder synced with EAC so it will be automatically synced into Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a user is set up to sync contacts, Einstein Activity Capture creates a folder called `Salesforce_Sync` **(Microsoft Exchange)** or a group called `Salesforce Sync` **(Google)** within the user’s email account.
Users choose which contacts sync by moving contacts into the `Salesforce_Sync` folder or `Salesforce Sync` group.

Renaming, moving, or deleting the `Salesforce_Sync` folder or `Salesforce Sync` group might prevent contacts from syncing.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aac_guidelines_sync.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks - I saw this in the docs. But does that mean that it will auto-create contacts for emails that don't exist in SF?

Comment: Yes, It will create contacts and email activities as well. You just need to move the contact in that folder/group.

Comment: My client doesn't want to be busy with it - he wants to be able to click 'Yes' and forget about it.

Comment: I guess there is no such option in EAC